# Check to see if specific text is within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to check if any specific text is within an array, so basically a stristr within an array. Currently I perform an in_array function but it will not pick it up is the text is only part of the array value;

e.g Search for "man" in the array("Manchester United","Liverpool", "Arsenal") would currently return nothing, but I need it to return Manchester united etc..

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$teams = array("Manchester United", "Liverpool", "Arsenal");
$term = "man";

foreach ($teams as $team) {
    if (stripos($team, $term) === false) {
        continue;
    }

    echo "Found match: $team\n";
}
?>
```

Or you could get fancy and use array_filter:

```
<?php
$teams = array("Manchester United", "Liverpool", "Arsenal");
$term = "man";
$results = array_filter($teams, function ($elt) use ($term) {
    return stripos($elt, $term) !== false;
});
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
function find($needle, array $haystack) {
    $matches = array();
    foreach($haystack as $value) {
        if(stristr($value, $needle) !== false) {
            $matches[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

$haystack = array("Manchester United", "Liverpool", "Arsenal");
print_r(find('man', $haystack));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Manchester United
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$items = array("Manchester United","Liverpool", "Arsenal");
$results = array();
$searchTerm = 'man';

foreach($items as $item) {
    if (stripos($item, $searchTerm) !== false) {
        $results[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: `stripos()` will do case-insensitive search